# node-postgres SELECT query succeeds when id column is targeted but fails when another column is targeted

Tags: postgresql

[image: Snapshot of the my stations table]

When I select from the table by targeting the station_id column like this:

```
const getStationById = async ( id ) => {
  try {
    const station = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM stations WHERE "station_id" = ${id}`)
    return station.rows[0]
  } catch (err) {
    return err
  }
}
```

It works normally.

But when I target another column like this:

```
const searchFinName = async (name) => {
 
  try {
    const stations = await pool.query(`SELECT station_id, fin_name, swe_name, address, city, operator, capacity, x_coordinate, y_coordinate FROM stations WHERE "fin_name" = ${name})
    return station.rows
  } catch (err) {
    return err
  }

}
```

it returns this error:

```
{"length":103,"name":"error","severity":"ERROR","code":"42703","position":"43","file":"parse_relation.c","line":"3666","routine":"errorMissingColumn"}.
```

I have not seen any other solution that helps, can someone please help me identify the problem, thanks.

Comment: You are missing the closing quote symbol ( ` )

Comment: Thanks Tim for the response. The missing backtick is just a typo here on StackOverflow, I have checked the code countless times and there is no typo there.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a problem with your logic, but rather with syntax or the amount of data being returned too large, which is not very likely.

1. There is a missing closing quote "`" in your syntax above.
2. Check that all column names passed in the query are correct.
3. Try using the following query:

   SELECT * FROM stations WHERE 'fin_name' = ${name}

As you are already projecting all the columns, using * would be wiser and can prevent the syntax fault that is most likely occurring.

Comment: Thanks for your response Saif, the backticks are placed correctly in my code. I have also used * in my code without success. The query pasted here with all the columns was copied from pgAdmin. The query works just fine in pgAdmin whether I use * or I specify all columns. I have also tried formatting the query as it is in your 3rd suggestion but I am still getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here that postgres parse `$name` variable as a column name not as a string.

So, the `$name` variable in your query should be surrounded by single quotes so that postgres can parse it as a string:

```
const stations = await pool.query(`SELECT station_id, fin_name, swe_name, address, city, operator, capacity, x_coordinate, y_coordinate FROM stations 
WHERE "fin_name" = '${name}'`)
```

Alternatively you can pass all the parameters in an array to the `query` function like this:

```
const stations = await pool.query(`SELECT station_id, fin_name, swe_name, address, city, operator, capacity, x_coordinate, y_coordinate FROM stations 
WHERE "fin_name" = $1` , [name]);
```

Comment: Hello Omar, thanks a lot but I still doesn't work. At this point, I think there is something wrong some dependency in my project. When I first encountered this problem I was using Sequelize, I immediately removed it in favour of node-postgres, but the problem has persisted. I'm now tempted to think the problem is with pg itself because the query works well on both psql and pgAdmin query tool.

Comment: After you changed it same error appears or another one ?

Comment: yes, the same error appears no matter how the query is formatted.

Comment: Aah! You won't believe that I didn't change anything but it works now! I just let the project be for a few days and when I resumed the query worked as if it never threw an error all its life.